# C++, AutoClick Buttons

Tags: c++, user-interface, automation

Has anyone any experience or ideas around the following.  I have a test application which i developed.  It has radio buttons, normal buttons, drop down menus, etc.  What I hope to do is write another application that would kick off my first application, automatically click the OK button which says 'welcome to the aplpication' and then select drop down options radio buttons, etc.

Is this possible or could anyone provide me with example code i could use to tweak towards what i want to do.

So far Ive managed the very simple task of kicking off my test application with this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
int main()
{   // Replace 'path' with the location of these files.   

    system( "\"D:/Test/Bin/Test.exe\"" ); 
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running the application with `system( "\"D:/Test/Bin/Test.exe\"" );` will not even give you the possibility of interacting with the application. `system()` blocks and wait until the inner application finishes before returning.

Radio buttons and such are graphical **user** interface. To interface with another program, one must provide some interprocess communication (IPC) interface. Making one program to use another program through a GUI may be possible, but it is certainly very difficult and suboptimal.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ivella.

Comment: It depends on purpose though. For testing the user interface, you want to emulate clicks to make the test behave as much like a user as possible. The only other reason to do this is driving closed third-party application whose author can't be bothered to add a programmatic API.

Answer (score 0):

[AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) is a scripting language that can drive another application's GUI in Windows.  AutoIt scripts can run standalone, but it's also available as a DLL, so you can embed its scripting within your `int main()` function if you really wanted to.

It sounds like AutoIt should do what you want, but if you have more specific questions, please edit this question to add them or post them as additional questions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to do it programmatically, but I have in the past used [autoit](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/), see  to script a simple GUI button pusher. It might allow you to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to code your app is using a calling to API system... If you use linux, you can read the X11 api, if you are in BSD read the posix api, and... if you are in windows, read de msdn... You should search how to manage windows handlers, and mouse api's...

I hope my answear can help you...

Comment: Thanks fbin - I think I will use some of the tools like AutoIt or Quick Test Pro for what I want to do - the scripting language of AutoIt seems pretty easy to pick up and should accomplish what I want - no point re-inventing the wheel right :)

Comment: ok! Autoit is a powerful scripting language for manage Gui's! Good LUck!